# Sine wave shows up on oscilloscope but keeps moving

Tags: arduino, oscilloscope, sine

I'm fairly new to electronics and new to using an oscilloscope.  I followed a youtube video to setup a sine wave using an Arduino Uno and a capacitor to detect on my Tektronix 2235.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojkUaCSFM30

However, the scope seems to constantly "move" through the sine wave like a bouncing ball instead of just displaying it like on a graph.  When just doing a simple digital 5V generation using the Arduino and no capacitor, it just shows a stable graph.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZjEv1hedKXllJgSrIjcxXV_FHNsyUWqc/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Is this based upon the rate of change of the voltage or something?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
int f = 2; //signal freq
float fs = 500.0; //sample freq
int sig[500]; //store signal
float t;  //time value


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  for (int i =0; i<500; i++) {
    t = (float) i / fs;

    sig[i] = (int) (127.0 * (sin(2*3.14*f*t) + 1.0) );  //127 is 1/2 of 255, the max voltage value
  }

}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i<500; i++) {
    analogWrite(10, sig[i]);
    delay(2);  //sampling interval
  }

}
```

The scope is set to 1V / div and 10 microseconds.

Comment: Sounds like you need to adjust the trigger mode or level on the scope.

Comment: This is a basic misunderstanding of how oscilloscopes work, you need to be in normal trigger mode.

Comment: fregas, I think Tektronix used to have some nice "tutorials" on using an oscilloscope. You really should read these. But separately, try and "think like an old-style oscilloscope" which didn't have any memory like modern digital ones do. If you were one of those, how would you make a sine wave "look stable?" You'd need to somehow "trigger" (cause the trace to reset back to the beginning left edge of the scope) at just the right moment of the sine wave. To do that, you'd want to trigger at some "voltage" point. The trigger circuitry does a lot of fancy stuff. It's important. Read about it.

Comment: fregas, if your triggering isn't set right or is set at a wrong voltage, then you will never figure out when to go back and re-draw the data. And so you'll just, probably, start redrawing at some random point (like when you get to the end of the display, you might just go back to the beginning, but at who-knows-where on the sine wave?) So the triggering circuits are really, really important to getting useful displays out of an oscilloscope. When you first are thinking about using the scope, you should think about "what exactly shall I trigger on?" That should be the first thing in mind.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  My cheapy US$300 DS1504 50 MHz, 4 channel storage scope has a "RUN/STOP" button. So I don't care if the waves are moving (often you just cannot get a "steady" sync, or don't know which channel to auto sync, etc). So I just press the "freeze" button, and then go for a cup of coffee, come back, and take my time, to leisurely zoom in or out, shift left or right on the frozen waveform to focus on the interesting portion, perhaps also press the download button to save the perfect photo to my 16GB USB memory stick (taking about 5 seconds for 800px wide screen capture).

Comment: _"I followed a youtube video to setup a sine wave using an arduino uno and a capacitor"_ - Link to Youtube video?

Comment: added a link to the video. :)

Comment: Finbarr and crasic are right in their comments... I just want to mention that most modern scopes also provides an auto-setup button. And most scopes I have worked with (even cheep ones) do a decent job in getting the setup right for most waveforms.

Comment: @fregas:  I see you have what looks like a digital scope parked on top of the 2235.  Have you compared what the two scopes display when connected to your 2Hz signal?

Comment: What’s in common with this? No horizontal trigger . http://tinyurl.com/y3vj34g4. At least have the ability.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - Thanks for the link!  I've never enjoyed doing math, so I never really took much interest in analog electronics(although I'm "better than your average bear") and spent most of my electronics career designing digital circuits.  Your link helps me visualize the current flow in some of the push-pull vintage amplifiers I have been repairing lately!  Still trying to understand the bias and current mirror circuits, both being offset from ground.  Anyways, Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to learn how to modify that design with mouse rubber band mode stretching ends of parts and mouse wheel to change values.  The scope properties are pretty good for measuring power, current or voltage. And undocked traces can be moved and stretched. Files saved as text or exported as links are handy too

Comment: Theres also undo and file >recover auto save

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a very low sweep time, and generating a very slow signal from your Arduino.

The code claims it is generating a 2 hertz signal.  That is, 2 cycles of the sine wave in one second.

If your scope were set to 10 microseconds per division like you say, then on your 10 division wide oscilloscope display you would only see 1/10000 of a second. You would only see a short section of the wave on screen, and it would look like a straight line.

Since you can see approximately 2 full cycles of the wave on the display, your time base is set to something like 0.1 seconds per division.

This explains why the trace "looks like a bouncing ball."

The Tektronix 2235 is an analog oscilloscope with a cathode ray tube (CRT) for a display.

It has no memory or analog to digital converter to capture the signal and hold on it screen.

The vertical amplifier (volts per division amplifier) directly drives a pair of electrostatic plates in the tube, causing the electron beam to move up and down.

The time base circuit directly drives a pair of electrostatic plates in the tube causing the beam to move from left to right across the display.

It draws the signal on the light emitting phosphor inside the display with that beam of electrons.

At low speeds, you can see the beam as a dot making its way across the display.

At high sweep speeds, the beam repeats fast enough that it looks like a solid line.

At slow sweep speeds like you are using, you see the spot from the beam as it moves - the "bouncing ball."

You will **not** get a nice line on the display of your Tektronix 2235 for a 2Hz signal like the guy got in the video.

He is using a digital oscilloscope that captures the signal with an analog to digital converter, stores the measurements in memory, then displays them on an LCD like a picture on your PC monitor.

What you are seeing is normal and correct for an analog oscilloscope.

---

Do **not** crank up the brightness of the display to try and get a solid line at slow sweep speeds.  You will damage the CRT.  If the tube gets damaged, then your scope is shot - replacing the tube will cost as much as replacing the whole scope, if you can get a replacement tube at all.

You have it set **very** bright in your video.  There is a reflection of the trace that goes across the face of the scope.

Turn the brightness down, **now** before using the scope for anything else.

---

If you really need to measure slow signals at low sweep speeds on an analog oscilloscope, then I recommend using [this software](https://github.com/JosephEoff/D43) together with a web camera in an enclosed mount as described [here.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/new-oscilloscope-camera)

The software has a [persistence mode](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/d43-persistance) that you can use to make slow signals more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Turn down brightness and focus if necessary to avoid burning out phosphor.

Your video H settings were not 10 microseconds. (μs)  but more like 10 milliseconds (ms) so 10cm takes 0.1s.

Settings on the right:

**Input Coupling** : DC , your frequency is too low for AC <10 HZ but OK for 50 Hz.

- phosphor is not memory type.

**Trigger Mode:** Auto
**Horizontal Mode:** A

Comment: Ah, you remind me those were my happy old days using a a very expensive (perhaps 10 time my monthly salary) Tektronix scope, excitedly watching at pico second time frame, diode switching times. Fast forward x decades, to 21th century, even cheap scopes me poor hobbyists use are all storage, digital and auto shutoff, cool LCD screen. There is no phosphor to burn :).

Comment: You remind me that my 1st computer I used at work was a WANG desktop during a summer job as a surveyor's assistant. Then a HP2825 when I graduated while my mentor used NOVA mini to design a 3D chess game..

Comment: Well, my first computer was CDC7600, IBM 026 punch card machine, and I used IBM360 JCL to submit my deck of cards of a one liner APL program to simulate Game of Life (Before I catch the clever corona virus sooner or later, I must now confess in time that I did not understand the APL program which I did not write, I just copycat!). I still remember one afternoon lead it to a staff only desk and showed me stupid looking 12" black and white, 12 x 24  TV set, with keyboard and said "Look Ma, no punch card, no 132 column line printer paper output, no computer room, / to continue, ...

Comment: no need to beg, steal, or borrow more computer seconds to complete your ***there is always one more bug*** Algol 60 assignment, ... In short, no nothing, ***only sweet dreams made of paperless stuff, screen, keyboard, whatever, ...*** - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeMFqkcPYcg.

Comment: Yes we also had access to the University computer IBM360 era and played lunar lander between classes on the teletype 300Bd phone modem.